# Angular design close button, border

Tags: angular, typescript, button, angular-material, angular-ui-router

This is my code. I want to show a close button only the X. The problem is that, this X as button it's showing there, but it has an outline colored when popup it's opened, and if i try to click somewhere it disappear this border/outline to X button.

```
<div class="row">
    <h3 mat-dialog-title class="float-left" style="margin-left:10px;font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;">Congratulation</h3>
    <button type="button" class="close modal-header" style="margin-left: 330px !important;" mat-button mat-dialog-close>&times;</button>
</div>
```

I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Add outline: none !important; in your css.

Comment: Could you post a small working example? It's a little difficult to decipher from the current html.

Comment: also it dose not work :(

Comment: <button type="button" mat-button mat-dialog-close>&times;</button> 
This is my code, i'm trying to hide the line square around the X. using outline, and border it dose not work.